# How to work with probabilistic classification with scikit learn SVC's?

Tags: numpy, machine-learning, scipy, nlp, scikit-learn

Firstly my data looks like this:

```
label|instances(sentences)
5    |1190
4    |839
3    |239
2    |204
1    |127
```

Then I cross validated:

```
from sklearn import cross_validation
kf = cross_validation.KFold(n=len(y),n_folds=10)

for train_index, test_index in kf:
    print "\nTRAIN:\n", train_index, "\n TEST:\n", test_index
    X_train, X_test = X_combined_features[train_index], X_combined_features[test_index]
    y_train, y_test = y[train_index], y[test_index]
```

From the [documentation](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.svm.SVC.html) I know that probabilistic metrics can be turned on as follows:

```
svm = SVC(probability=True)
```

I would like to work with probabilistic classification and SVMs, so let's assume that I read the data, then I do the following:

```
from sklearn.svm import SVC
svm = SVC(kernel='linear', probability=True)
svm.fit(reduced_training_matrix, y)
output_proba = svm.predict_proba(reduced_testing_matrix)
print output_proba
```

Then I got this:

```
[[ 0.06351278  0.05312154  0.07709772 ...,  0.41958171  0.00076087
   0.00076095]
 [ 0.05813505  0.05373973  0.08617775 ...,  0.47467149  0.00082695
   0.00082701]
 [ 0.05576647  0.04756668  0.08216568 ...,  0.47984425  0.00077685
   0.00077693]
 ..., 
 [ 0.05983482  0.03972051  0.07636607 ...,  0.4853006   0.00070774
   0.00070783]
 [ 0.05813505  0.05373973  0.08617775 ...,  0.47467149  0.00082695
   0.00082701]
 [ 0.05989075  0.04822012  0.07795987 ...,  0.48084117  0.00073095
   0.00073101]]
```

Several questions arised from the above excercise: What is that array output  (i.e. what does it mean?), Am I doing things in the right way?... If not, how should I need to proceed in order to use probabilistic classification with SVC?.

**Update:**

```
vector_of_probabilities_for_sample= reduced_training_matrix[j,:]
print vector_of_probabilities_for_sample.toarray()

[[ 0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.]]


probability_of_corresponding_class = reduced_training_matrix[j,:]
print probability_of_corresponding_class.toarray()

[[ 0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.]]
```

Answer (score 1):

> What is that array output

Probability of some label for each corresponding sample from `reduced_training_matrix`. Every i-th column here - probability of corresponding class `svm.classes_[i]`, every j-th row - vector of probabilities for sample `reduced_training_matrix[j,:]`. Obviously sum of each row equals to 1.

> Am I doing things in the right way?

Yes.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. I edited the question and added how I am cross validating. Do you think the way I crossvalidated is the right way?... I have doubts since I have pretty bad performance.

Comment: @johndoe, i honestly  don't get you. What are you trying to do? Where is cross validation? Why you use your samples matrix and then name rows of it as 'probability_of_corresponding_class'?

Comment: I just want to do an example of how to work with probabilistic SVC scores... but I dont understand the documentation example. I give these names based in your answer... Could you provide just a quick example... just to understand the correct way to use the aforementioned approach?. Thanks!

Comment: @johndoe, but everything ok in your previous examples (except Updated section). What exactly you want to do? Cross Validation? But you don't need to use probabilities in CV.

Comment: Thank you very much.... Im just trying to understand. However, with regards to the CV I thought that every time I wanted to classify something it is a good idea to do CV to reduce the bias. For that reason I added the CV... so, CV is not necessary?

Comment: In Machine Learning Cross Validation used only to get some approximate prediction accuracy of learned model on general totality. Based on this score you can judge if this model behaves accurate enough, or compare CV scores of different models to choose best one. So yes, CV is not necessary if you don't want to compare models.

You can read more about CV here http://scikit-learn.org/stable/model_selection.html#model-selection

Or look at example of CV http://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/model_selection/plot_underfitting_overfitting.html